# MongoDB and consistent hashing

Tags: mongodb, distributed, sharding, consistent-hashing

MongoDB has well-documented sharding feature.

All I need is simpler (both to deploy and configure) and faster consistent hashing type of data distribution (like Dynamo, Cassandra or Voldemort). Is there a way to achieve that with MongoDB?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right tool for the job? When you just want a fast key/value store, then maybe Memcached is what you need.

Comment: @Philipp: memcached doesn't have auto-sharding, AFAIK. Maybe Riak is a better choice. Or Cassandra.

Comment: While I agree that Riak is better suited for our needs, I hoped that similar trick is available with MongoDB, which we get used to. Anyway, thank you, it looks like we need to switch to Riak.

Comment: Consistent hashing is being planned for a future release of MongoDB.  See https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2001.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like MongoDB 2.4 now includes Hashed sharding, what might be what you want

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-internals/#hashed-shard-keys

Comment: This link redirects to MongoDB version 3.4. The hashed sharding is not consistent hashing, rather it is used to ensure uniform distributions of collections in DB. The objective of consistent hashing is to ensure minimal data movement in a dynamic system. So the answer to asked question is still no, till yet.

Answer (score 1):

I am just learning MongoDB and was trying to find the answer to this. However, the way I see this is that it MAY be possible to simulate this by using range sharding on a precalculated hash, then carefully configuring splits.

Comment: That sounds like a smart thing.